# can't install pycaw using pip

Tags: python, pip

I tried installing pycaw with help of pip. It raised this error. How can I solve this error or download pycaw manually?

...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
C:\Users\hp>pip install pycaw
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pycaw
  Using cached pycaw-20181226.tar.gz (5.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [25 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2851, in get_entry_map
          ep_map = self._ep_map
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2813, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: _ep_map. Did you mean: '_dep_map'?

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-q7kqui7h\pycaw_66d329da2c8e4069ab3ad04fde4ecaee\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
          setup(name='pycaw',
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
          _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 453, in __init__
          for ep in pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('distutils.setup_keywords'):
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 641, in <genexpr>
          for entry in dist.get_entry_map(group).values()
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2853, in get_entry_map
          ep_map = self._ep_map = EntryPoint.parse_map(
        File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2538, in parse_map
          raise ValueError("Entry points must be listed in groups")
      ValueError: Entry points must be listed in groups
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions as I can see for your problem:

- Check that you have the Visual Studio C++ build tools installed:

  - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pl/visual-cpp-build-tools/
- Maybe try add the following to the installation command: `--use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures` for example: `pip install pandas --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures`
- potentially you can install this development branch: pip install

  - https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/archive/develop.zip
    and after that, you can instal requirements